# Firefox keeps asking me to download a .php file

Tags: firefox, php

From a couple of weeks ago, Firefox keeps asking me from time to time to download or open a file named "as.php". Sometimes the message will repeated and the windows will pile up. The option shown for opening is Xcode. I always click cancel, but I want them to stop, it is useless and annoying.

I've tried deleting the mimetypes.rdf and the handlers.json files, but it doesn't work.

Any help or insight will be thanked.

I'm using Firefox 67.0.4 (automatically updated June 12, 18 and 20, which may coincide with the starting of this issue) and OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: Maybe it's the server's error by sending a bad `Content-Type` header.

Comment: It could be. How can I solve it if that's the case?

Comment: If that's the case, then there's probably nothing you can do towards the solution. Maybe you should check the download URL first.